# Can't install Xcode on my mac?

Tags: macos, xcode

I want to install metasploit, and I know that xcode is needed. Now the problem is, that even though xcode is on my computer and I downloaded it from the app store, this occurs:

```
./msf_install.sh -i -p msfconsole -r
[*] Log file with command output and errors /tmp/msfinstall-Oct-03-15-003057.log
[*] Verifying that Development Tools and Java are installed:
[*] Java is installed.
[*] Xcode is not installed on this system. Install from the Apple AppStore.
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you've opened Xcode and installed the components. To install the command line tools, run `xcode-select --install`.

Comment: I tried but it didn't worked. I got this message in my terminal instead: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates

Answer (score 0):

I installed the metasploit from this link it is working fine.
http://www.darkoperator.com/installing-metasploit-framewor/